# ajaxStart() on forge.request.ajax

Tags: trigger.io

For showing a loading screen, we listen to the jQuery ajaxStart() event the following way:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        //show loading screen
    });
```

However, this event doesn't get fired sending forge.reques.ajax() requests (at least is seems so).

Is there already a solution like that for forge or do I have to write that event by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't currently exist in forge, but its pretty easy to implement:

```
var onAjaxStart = function () {
    // show loading screen
}
var onAjaxEnd = function () {
    // hide loading screen
}
var myAjax = function (params) {
    onAjaxStart();
    var success = params.success;
    params.success = function () {
        onAjaxEnd();
        success && success();
    };
    forge.request.ajax(params);
}
```

Then us myAjax(...) instead of forge.request.ajax(...).

Comment: Thanks for that answer, do you know where I can hook in to stop/hide my loading screen when receiving the response?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a function that will always be called on success, hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for the update, works fine -- in addition, I only had to make sure to pass through some additional parameters of succeed()